# python sqlite3 reopen database

Tags: python, sqlite

Im getting this error:

```
 sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.
```

How do I open the database again, after I closed it?

I was thinking closing it and then reopening would be a good idea because I have a loop that will be running for several hours:

```
for x in tweets:
    conn = sqlite3.connect("...")
    ....
    conn.close()
    time.sleep(1800)  #30 minutes
```

But when it gets to the second loop, it gives me the closed database error.

Comment: Its probably better (and more efficient / bug free) just to do the occasional `conn.commit()`

Comment: There is no need to close the database connection until you are done.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, look at the sleep. I guess he doesn't want to hold onto the connection for next 30 minutes.

Comment: @user3885927: unless the OP has multiple connections open, that doesn't make any difference, other than that it may destroy any caches the connection holds and could help with the next task.

Comment: If there isn't any problem with holding the connection for about 12 hours, then I guess I don't need to close-reopen.

Comment: If you are writing to the SQLite database, you indeed want to commit and close so that a read lock is released from other clients trying to access the same.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say there is something else at play here. I ran the following code using Python 2 and 3 (though for Python 2 I only tested with a time.sleep of 2 seconds) and it worked fine.

```
import sqlite3, time
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

# Set up table (adding because doing nothing with database didn't cause the error)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE tweets (tweet text)')
conn.commit()

tweets = ['a','b','c']

for x in tweets:
    print('Tweet: ',x)
    conn = sqlite3.connect("example.db")

    # Extra stuff to try make it error
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO tweets VALUES (?)', x)
    conn.commit()

    conn.close()
    time.sleep(1800)  #30 minutes


# Cleanup so I can run test a few times
conn = sqlite3.connect("example.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('DROP TABLE tweets')
```

I can get this code to produce the same error you received if I comment out the `conn` assignment in the for loop.